# Android WebView open app and load link

Tags: android, android-webview

I have users that receive a link to my website via email.(EG. example.com/special folder/file) When they click on the link it prompts them to open my app as it should. However I am unable to figure out how to load that link they clicked in my app. (Each user is sent a specific page tailored to them) From the research I have done all the examples are loading the website using:

```
String url ="http://example.com";

 myview.loadUrl(url);
```

Again I am trying to load the orginal link they clicked on. Not the static URL.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or better yet provide a sample of how i would achieve this it would be much appreciated.

**Update1**

To put it simply It works like youtube. If you were sent a link via email to a youtube video it would prompt you to use the youtube app. Then load the video you were sent. All i need is my app to load the webpage the user was sent

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of loading `webview` using `ProgressDialog` for user feedback.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    String url="http://www.google.com";

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                  
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.setMessage("Loading..Please wait.");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    webView.loadUrl(url);



    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! So by looking at your example, would just load the example.com page. Not the original link that was clicked?

Comment: replace www.example.com with your page like www.google.com

Comment: Yea, that isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to load the original URL they clicked on because the sub-file is specific to them. Sorry if i didn't make that clear.

Comment: "I have users that receive a link to my website via email" i cant understand your mean but if you want to find the links that comes to your app you must write php code i will do this for you now in next post

Comment: I send the users a link that is specific to them. In a email i send a link like example.com/special folder/file. When the app opens i need the webview to load example.com/special folder/file. Not just example.com.

Comment: To put it simply It works like youtube. If you were sent a link via email to a youtube video it would prompt you to use the youtube app. Then load the video you were sent. All i need is my app to load the webpage the user was sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                 hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Please check and let me know if you are facing any issue.

Comment: From what i see its loading a page that is hard coded. When the app opens i need it to load the original link the user clicked to open the app.